# How to use navigation fragment item checked with custom color?

Tags: android, navigationview

I am using fragment instead of Navigation view. I want to set custom color highlight when fragment item clicked.

Comment: What are you using for the list item? I mean Listview or Recycler view.

Comment: i not using listview or Recycler view.i m using custom fragment layout and set clickListener on that views.

Comment: Can you please post the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

```
MY scuode code:---
  use within Navitaionview--app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"

like Example:--
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/nav.background"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"

nav_item_background.xml:---

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"   android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
<item android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background.default" />
```

Comment: pls get my question..i m not using navigation view